# What's the difference between import { compose } from 'recompose' vs import compose from 'recompose/compose

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

What's the difference between these two javascript import styles:

`import { compose } from 'recompose'`
`import compose from 'recompose/compose`

I'm looking for the details on how they work. Is there are any tradeoffs between the two? Performance impacts?

Note: I'm using Webpack as bundler

Comment: It depends on what the module `recompose` does. If it just re-exports from `/compose`, there's not much difference

Comment: The one imports a named export from a module, the other imports the default export from a submodule

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, the link to the duplicated question gave me the answer I was looking for.